# Concrete numerical example of Complex Product in ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking intensely at the definition of *Complex Product* from a class note on Modules in Ring Theory that goes like this:

> Let $P$ and $Q$ be non-empty subsets of $R$, a commutative ring with 1. Define $PQ$ to be the set of all elements
>   $$p_1q_1 + \ldots + p_nq_n$$
>   with  $p_1, \dots, p_n \in P$ and $q_1, \ldots q_n \in Q.$ Then the set $PQ$ is called the *Complex Product* of $P$ and $Q.$

I am not sure if I can understand this definition correctly when it comes to a concrete numerical example: What happens if the number of elements of $P$ is different from that of $Q$? Does $p_1$ has to match up only with $q_1$, and $p_2$ with $q_2$, etc.? I did not see any other explanation except the above paragraph.

Therefore, I would like somebody to help my understanding by giving me a *Complex Product* $PQ$ from this concrete example $-$ please: Let $R = \mathbb Z_6 = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 \}$, a classic example of commutative ring with 1, and let's make the order of subset $P$ different from that subset $Q$ with the following: $P = \{0, 1, 2\}$ and $Q = \{4, 5\}.$

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider all pairwise products of an element of $P$ and an element of $Q$, then consider all possible sumes of a finite number of these products.

For the examples you gave:

- *Pairwise products:* $\{0, 4,5,2\}$
- *Sums of products:*
- one term: $\{ 0,2,4,5\}$
- two terms: $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Thus $P\cdot Q=\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z$.

*Note:*
This  *complex product* is the way the product of two ideals $\mathfrak{a, b}$ is defined. The reason for this is the ‘naive’  definition (all possible products of an element $a\in \mathfrak a$ with an element $b\in \mathfrak b$ ) is *not* an ideal. The ideal generated by these products is precisely their complex product.

Comment: I am sorry I am late. You have got my up-vote and green check. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome!  Always glad to be helpful.